# Pi Camera detect almost full black image

Tags: camera

I'm capturing images using picamera and I need to detect when the sensor is covered by a hand, so almost full black image. what is the easier way to do that in python?

Comment: I have the same problem.  I am using PIR and Pi Camera to detect my two naughty cats coming into the bed room.  Usually the fat cat covers the whole view, while thin cat only half view.  So I need to use python to monitor if the fat cat is coming in.  I have written a simple statistical pattern recognition function.  PIR triggers Rpi python which counts the black pixels. More that 70% black means fat cat, else thin cat.  And I count the number of times fat cat coming in every day , staying for how long each time, ..  My smart cat food dispenser has a cat face detector to / continue, ...

Comment: And this is my fat cat dieting food dispenser design notes - 
CAT HOME DIY Q&A - SOLENOID HOW TO Postby tlfong01 » 2019-Jan-11 Fri 3:31 pm
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=230984&hilit=cat#p1414845

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing specific to a Raspberry in the question, but you can add the values of all pixels in the image, and if the result is below your threshold, it is considered too dark. Usually, a black pixel is represented by the value zero.

Comment: Off-topic questions should not be answered, per the help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: You may answer off topic questions in a comment.

Comment: that's what I meant but how do I read the values of all pixels in the image?